# Inability to install Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX or Spreadsheet::XLSX using ppm with ActivePerl v5.22.1

Tags: excel, perl, spreadsheet, xlsx, activeperl

I need to read .xlsx and .xlsm files from PERL scripts, but am having trouble installing an XLSX parser using ppm.  Am using ActivePerl version 5.22.1.

I have no problem installing and using Spreadsheet::ParseExcel (which only works on .xls files up to Excel 2003):

ppm install spreadsheet-parseexcel
Downloading www.sisyphusion.tk.ppm packlist...not found
Downloading Spreadsheet-ParseExcel-0.65...done
Unpacking Spreadsheet-ParseExcel-0.65...done
Generating HTML for Spreadsheet-ParseExcel-0.65...done
Updating files in site area...done
  30 files installed

But ppm install spreadsheet-parsexlsx gives:

Downloading www.sisyphusion.tk.ppm packlist...not found
ppm install failed: Can't find any package that provides spreadsheet-parsexlsx

and similar for spreadsheet-xlsx.

I tried getting around the problem by using a lower-level package like Spreadsheet::Read; this worked fine on an Excel 2003 .xls file but gave an error message that no XLSX parser was installed when I tried it on a .xlsx file -- a spreadsheet parser with dependencies on ParseXLSX won't help.

I've also spent about an hour searching the web for other instances of the same issue but have found no definite solution (maybe I just have not searched in the right way; I am relatively new to this).  I do not currently have a C compiler on my windows desktop or much experience with Makefiles and have never installed a PERL module except using ppm.  So if you have alternate installation instructions (not through ppm) please present them at a *very* basic level, not assuming that I know anything about CPAN or manual file installation.

With this background, can anyone help me to install the Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX module or otherwise efficiently find a way to parse .xlsx files with PERL?

Thanks very much for your help,
Loren

Comment: Have you tried `cpan Spreadsheet::XLSX`? By the way, the language is "Perl"

Answer (score 0):

The message:
Downloading www.sisyphusion.tk.ppm packlist.
shows that you are targeting the Sisyphusion PPM repository. That's a specialist repository with a limited selection of resources.

The error:
not found ppm install failed: Can't find any package 
indicates that the repo you targeted does not contain a pre-compiled copy of the module for the version of Perl you are currently running.

There are several general purpose repos that have more content available. In particular, the default repository prepared by ActiveState:
http://code.activestate.com/ppm/Spreadsheet-ParseExcel/

Answer (score 0):

The activestate ppm install documentation says that this module isn't supported in perl 5.22 on windows 32/64 (but it is supported in previous windows perl versions such as 5.20)

see https://code.activestate.com/ppm/spreadsheet-XLSX/